# pandas dataframe reassign row with 10-character phone number

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, df_data, which has a column named "number" with phone numbers in it of various forms. For example, the phone number could be in the form of 234-567-8901, 2345678901, or even (234)-567-8901. I am trying to efficiently change each row in this column to be a phone number with just numbers (i.e. 2345678901). My code does so, however, since there is almost 1M rows, the code runs forever and doesn't even finish in most cases. Is there a better way to do this? At the end of the day I am interested in getting a column of just area codes. Some values in the column don't exist and have a value of nan. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
for i in range(np.shape(df_data)[0]):
    j = df_data.loc[i,'number']
    if(j==j):
        df_data.loc[i,'number']= re.findall("\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}",j)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're overthinking this, but just remove anything that isn't a digit from that column?

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'number' : ['234-567-8901', '(234)-567-8901', '2345678901']})
print(df)
           number
0    234-567-8901
1  (234)-567-8901
2      2345678901

df['number'] = df.number.str.replace(r'\D+','')
print(df)
       number
0  2345678901
1  2345678901
2  2345678901
```

Comment: Yeah I was definitely overthinking that part. Do you have a recommendation on how to just get the first 3-digits in each row even when some rows are nan values? I guess I am overthinking when it comes to pandas.